# Cannot login ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, login, 15.04

I've got a problem logging into my user from the graphical start screen. 
When I write my password there is som flicker and some error messages on the screen before it returns to login again.This happened after I installed the latest kernel this morning. I have purged the 3.19.0-21-generic kernel, and I have tried to start the machine in recovery mode. My machine does not respond to the pressing shift (left or right) during startup.

I need some good advice here, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Dag R

Answer (score 1):

You either have video driver problems or permission problems with some required files in your home folder.
First, you need to enter terminal by pressing ctrl - alt - F1 in login screen. Then do 
   sudo chown -R /home/username
to restore permissions.

Comment: I think it's a permission problem. I did some changes in some mail settings in my home folder yesterday. I used sudo to change those files. The files .msmtprc, .fetchmailrc, bashrc, procmailrc and muttrc were changed with sudo. when I press ctrl alt f1, I get a message no directory, logging in with HOME=/

Comment: Try creating a new user with `useradd`

Comment: I have tried to purge these programs, but it seems there is still a permission problem. I get a message after chown -R username /home/username cannot open <username> no such file or folder

Comment: ... where <username> is your actual user name. May be even your home folder name does not match your user name any more.

Comment: I tried to make a new user but same happens. I can log in as guest, so it seems it isn't anything wrong video driver. when I from commandline cd as root into the home folder. the folders are still there with the content they had before this problem occured